# How to calculate $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \left[(x+a)^{1+\frac1x}-(x) ^{1+\frac{1}{x+a}}\right]$

Tags: limits

How to calculate  $$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \left[(x+a)^{1+\frac1x}-(x) ^{1+\frac{1}{x+a}}\right]$$ 
The limit equals a but any hints for the method?

Comment: As an idea, set $x=a\,y$, pull out an $a$ and then argue why something along the lines of $(1+y)^{1+\delta}-y^{1+\epsilon}$ will go to $1$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2148367/72031

Answer (score 3):

Let us consider $$A=(x+a)^{1+\frac1x}\qquad \text {and} \qquad B=(x) ^{1+\frac{1}{x+a}}$$
$$A=(x+a)^{1+\frac1x}\implies \log(A)=\left({1+\frac1x}\right)\log(x+a)$$ Using Taylor we then have
$$\log(A)=\log \left({x}\right)+\frac{a+\log
   \left({x}\right)}{x}+\frac{a-\frac{a^2}{2}}{x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3
   }\right)$$
$$A=e^{\log(A)}=x+a+\log \left({x}\right)+\frac{2
   \left(a-\frac{a^2}{2}\right)+\left(a+\log \left({x}\right)\right)^2}{2
   x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$
$$B=(x) ^{1+\frac{1}{x+a}}\implies \log(B)=\left({1+\frac{1}{x+a}}\right)\log(x)$$
$$\log(B)=\log \left({x}\right)+\frac{\log \left({x}\right)}{x}-\frac{a \log
   \left({x}\right)}{x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$
$$B=e^{\log(B)}=x+\log \left({x}\right)+\frac{-2 a \log \left({x}\right)+\log
   ^2\left({x}\right)}{2 x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$
$$A-B=a\left(1+\frac{1+2  \log
   \left({x}\right)}{x}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$

Trying with $x=10^6$ and $a=\pi$, the exact value would be $3.1416826014$ while the approximation leads to $3.1416826006$.

Answer (score 2):

We can see two main things from a first glance at this problem. The first is that both exponents approach $1$ equivalently. Even though the denominator has $a$, as $x$ gets very large, the fraction contained in the exponent approaches $0$ at the same rate. Secondly, knowing that the exponents go to $1$, we compare $x+a$ to $x$. Note that we can only compare them since both exponents are equivalent in the sense of a limit. Clearly, $x+a-x$ is $a$, so the final answer is $a$.

Comment: Thx for the hint, I know the answer but interested in a decent way

Comment: The argument is sort of hand waving.

Comment: @paramanand Singh my apologies. I was under the impression this was an acceptable solution for the problem as this is often how I was taught to approach limits from a preliminary perspective. I can try to add in some more concrete demonstration

Comment: I think the kind of argument you have used may fail in different situation. It is better to use standard theorems to evaluate limits rather than rely on your intuition.